# How can I change the Google Docs (Sheets, Slides) user interface design?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-workspace-for-business, google-slides

I have several Google accounts. I noticed that the user interface of G Suite Apps in my new account is different from the one in my old account. Could you please tell whether I can choose it and how I can do it?

Old UI:

[image: old UI]

New UI:

[image: new UI]

Comment: I see absolutely no difference between the screenshots.

Comment: @Ramhound There are sine small differences, but they seem incredibly subtle. Like look at the “Sheet” tab in the lower left of each sheet. And the “Share” button. I have no idea how those alone could be disorienting.

Comment: it indeed was identical before I uploaded the same image twice.. and yes @JakeGould, those subtle differences are exactly what I am asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. This change is made by Google. Eventually, it will be all updated to the new design, you just hit the period of "change in progress".

> **What’s changing:**
>
> Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, and Sites will be getting
>   a new look and feel on the web. While there are no functionality
>   changes, users will notice some visual improvements, including:
>
> - Interface typography that uses Google’s custom-designed and
>     highly-legible typefaces
> - Controls (like buttons, dialogues, and
>     sidebars) that are updated and consistent
> - Iconography that is legible
>     and crisp, with a fresh feel The four products in this update join
>     other G Suite products like Gmail and Calendar in sharing a common
>     design language.
>
> **[https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/01/material-design-for-google-docs-sheets.html)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to change the UI, but it's quite difficult. It's in CSS that you have to tweak.

I already tried using CSS editors to change the style. Although some parts of the Google Docs UI changed, the rest did not.

I'm not using a CSS tweaker extension right now, but you can try one. I just searched for one (I don't remember the one I used) and here's the link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en

Just ask how to make a CSS if you don't know how to make one.